# node.js - having problem deploying node js server on vercel error 500

Tags: express, vercel

I want to ask. I created a node js server project using express and want to deploy it on vercel for serverless. why when I deploy it has a server error 500 problem,
**this my index.js code**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const registerRoutes = require("./routes/registerRoutes");
const articleRoutes = require("./routes/articleRoutes");
const documentRoutes = require("./routes/documentRoutes");
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
const port = process.env.DB_PORT;
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", err);
  });

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/register", registerRoutes);
app.use("/document", documentRoutes);
app.use("/article", articleRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("serve ris running");
});
```

**and this my vercel.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "react-jwt": "^1.2.0",
    "vercel": "^33.2.0"
  }
}
```

location file[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5c0X.png)

**how to fix it? so that serverless can be deployed and used. your help means a lot**